# Springboot test how to resolve controller's parameter to object

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a method signature like this in controller. when i try to write a unit test for it. it returns 500 instead of 404.
it looks like it is not able to convert the {id} to an Optional
is there any setting I need to do so it can auto convert the parameter to an object?

Thanks

```
@RequestMapping("/propagationStores")
public class PropagationStoreController {


    private StoreRepository storeRepository;
    private CustomValidator validator;
    public PropagationStoreController(StoreRepository storeRepository) {
        this.storeRepository = storeRepository;

    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public Resource<StoreDto> getById(@PathVariable("id") Optional<Store> storeOptional) {

        return storeOptional
            .map(StoreConverter::toDto)
            .map(store -> {
                Resource<StoreDto> resource = new Resource<>(store);
                resource.add(new Link("http://localhost").withTitle("localhost"));
                return resource;
        }).orElseThrow(ResourceNotFoundException::new);
    }
```

when I try to test the getById method using the following code. I am getting 500 instead of 400

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class PropagationStoreControllerIT {


    @MockBean
    StoreRepository storeRepository;
    @MockBean
    CustomValidator customValidator;


    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testGetById() throws Exception {
        when(storeRepository.findById(1l)).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
        mockMvc.perform(get("/propagationStores/1")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().is4xxClientError());
    }
}
```

I was expecting status 404, but I am getting 500.

the log as the following.

```
   MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /propagationStores/1
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = local.tux.propagation.controller.PropagationStoreController
           Method = public org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<local.tux.propagation.dto.Store$StoreDto> local.tux.propagation.controller.PropagationStoreController.getById(java.util.Optional<local.tux.propagation.evaluator.domain.Store>)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 500
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /propagationStores/1
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = local.tux.propagation.controller.PropagationStoreController
           Method = public org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<local.tux.propagation.dto.Store$StoreDto> local.tux.propagation.controller.PropagationStoreController.getById(java.util.Optional<local.tux.propagation.evaluator.domain.Store>)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 500
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Range for response status value 500 
Expected :CLIENT_ERROR
Actual   :SERVER_ERROR
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your controller method as:

```
public Resource<StoreDto> getById(@PathVariable("id") Optional<String> id) {
    ......
}
```

`id` can be converted to a string or a number, not into a `Store` class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that works, but I want to see if there is a way in the test environment can let the controller resolve the object itself.

Comment: the Store was able to resolve outside of the test env.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by using adding the @TestConfiguration. It looks like 
@MockBean interrupt the normal spring boot initialization, it doesn't register the converter. In order to make it work, we need to register ourself.

```
 @TestConfiguration
    static class InternalConfig {
        @Bean
        WebMvcConfigurer configurer() {
            return new WebMvcConfigurer() {

                @Override
                public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
                    registry.addConverter(String.class, Store.class, id -> staticRepository.getOne(Long.parseLong(id)));
                }
            };
        }
    }
```